# How to return results as a total number, rather than +1+1+1?

Tags: shell

I have a check that checks how many files are missing in the database. Everything works but when my code runs and outputs the results, there are 3 files missing but it is displayed like  "+1+1+1".

The code I am using is errcount=$errcount+1

Why does the code not accumulate the results?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way:

```
errcount=$(expr $errcount + 1)
```

(Note the spaces)

Answer (score 1):

This is a string operation:

```
errcount=$errcount+1
```

It does not do math.

#### POSIX shells

If you want the shell to do arithmetic, you can use the `$((...))` construct:

```
errcount=$((errcount+1))
```

#### Bash

Bash has additional non-POSIX extensions for incrementing a variable:

```
((errcount=errcount+1))
```

Or:

```
((errcount++))
```